# Is there a way to detect when bottom app tray is opened on iPad using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, events, ipad, focus

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to use JavaScript to detect when a user triggers a gesture on iPad (and probably to a larger extent most iOS devices) that brings up certain UI elements. I need to perform certain checks should that happen but have no idea how to go about it. In particular, I'm trying to check for when a user brings up the app tray at the bottom of the iPad as seen in the picture below but it would be nice if there was a general solution to all such gestures like those shown here https://ipadpilotnews.com/2020/04/all-the-gestures-ipad-pilots-need-to-know-using-an-ipad-pro-without-a-home-button/ [image: App tray]

Would really appreciate if anyone can point in the right direction. I have tried creating event listeners for blur and focus as suggested in some other stack overflow question but those don't seem to work for what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How might one force-show the mobile Safari bottom nav bar to show programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644584/how-might-one-force-show-the-mobile-safari-bottom-nav-bar-to-show-programmatical)

Comment: Thanks @ManasKhandelwal but unfortunately it doesn't really.